# Set value in one servlet and access it from different servlet

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7

I have a servletOne running in local TOMCAT and servletTwo is deployed in different TOMCAT in remote location. I want to access values (Array/ArrayList) that is set in servletTwo. I am not sure how to do it. I have looked at different example but nothing is working. This is what I have so far. Here is my doPost

```
 doGet(req, resp);

//doGet
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{
 ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    al.add("valOne");
    al.add("valTwo");
    //Should I use this
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println(al);
    //Or should I use this
    req.setAttribute("ArrayList", al);
}
```

Now I would like to access the arraylist from the servletOne

In servletOne I have,

```
try
    {
        URL url = new URL("http://myhost:8080/servletTest");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        BufferedReader in =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));

        String response;
        while ((response = in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            System.out.println(response);

        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException ex)
    {
        // handle this exception
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        // handle this exception
    }

 }
```

I don't think it will work as I am getting the value as string not as an array from the servletOne. Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  JSON:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{
 ArrayList al = new ArrayList();

    al.add("valOne");
    al.add("valTwo");
    //Should I use this
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println(al);
    //Or should I use this
   // req.setAttribute("ArrayList", al);

//create al object to JSOn and send it another servlet on another tomcat


  Gson gson=new Gson();

  String jsonlist=gson.toJson(al)

  String url = "http://example.com/query?q=" + URLEncoder.encode(jsonlist,    "UTF-8");

}
```

Comment: Is encodeURIComponent and JSON.stringify available in JAVA?

Comment: you can use JSON lib in java   JSONObject obj = ...
String jsonString = obj.toString();

Comment: Could you please replace,  encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(al)); with your proposed java solution. Thanks

Comment: Edited the solution please refer , Hope it is useful to you.